# Notion of convergence of random variables of growing dimensionality

Tags: probability, weak-convergence

When $Y_1, Y_2, \dots Y_n$ be a sequence of $d$-variate random variables we have the notion of convergence in distribution where we say $Y_n \implies Y_{\infty}$ if the corresponding distribution functions $F_n$ converges to $F$ (the distribution function of $Y_{\infty}$) pointwise wherever $F$ is continuous. This makes sense as both $F_n$ and $F$ have the same domain $\mathbb{R}^d$.

How does it translate for random variables where the dimension also changes with $n$. For instance, let $X_1, X_2, \dots$ be a sequence of random variables defined on the same probability space but of different dimensionality, i.e., $X_n: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{p_n}$ where $p_n$ is a sequence of real numbers with $p_n \rightarrow \infty$. Is there any notion of convergence where we can say $X_n$ converges to $X_{\infty}: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^\infty$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, and hope that any finite-dimensional restrictions of $X_n$ s converge to the corresponding finite-dimensional restrictions of $X_{\infty}$?